# What are some recommended Master's degree programs for individuals interested in specializing in the development of MI(L)P solvers?

Tags: reference-request

There are tons of Masters programs across North America and Europe focused on OR/Industrial Engineering.

I am interested especially in solver technology and would be very grateful if someone could help me in choosing a MS program that offers a curriculum and faculty specifically geared towards my goal.

I have looked at a few programs in Germany as it seems almost everyone working on MIP solvers is based there but I am not too sure if they are offered in English and that kind of limits my options.

Apologies, if this is off-topic, but since OR folks hang out here, I figured this would be the best place to ask.

Comment: There's a Discord server where some OR types hang out. If you don't get any help here (and if you are registered on Discord), message me here and I'll send you an invitation to it.